# Deploy Azure Cloud Service from Web Deploy or SDK

Tags: azure, web-deployment

I'm fooling around with Azure.

I found this guide on [Continuous Delivery for Cloud Applications in Windows Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery) and thought if there's a way to use either Web Deploy or the Azure SDK to do the actual deployment, rather than Powershell?

I want to deploy the same package as a Cloud Service. The Cloud Service may not exist, so it need to create it. If it exists, it should just update the package.

**Update**
I want to do this from a Windows Service that I already have (currently deploying to a local IIS). It's important that it can be done from some kind of programming interface, but if Powershell is only option, so be it.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that powershell is the only way to do it and make a cloud package in the past.  The powershell script uses the SDK, so in theory you could write a command line program to do the same thing that powershell is doing, but i dont know what that would necessarily buy you.  Do you need a powershell sample to do this or you just don't want to run powershell?  Here is a post on how to do it that i found:  http://adambird.com/automating-azure-deployment-with-windows-powe
Also docs here on the cmdlets.

http://wappowershell.codeplex.com/documentation

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's no problem to *make* the package. MSBuild with the Package target does that. It's the actual deployment to Azure that creates a new Cloud Service or updates an existing Cloud Service that I'm trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: I think this is the new Azure-Powershell reference? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152841

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use PowerShell there are other ways you can deploy i.e VS2010/AzureSDK.

Web Deploy is not a suggested method to deploy your package to Windows Azure due to some severe limitation however you can take a look on how to configure it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud/archive/2011/04/19/enabling-web-deploy-for-windows-azure-web-roles-with-visual-studio.aspx).

If you want to deploy using Windows Azure SDK, you sure are using VS2010 with it and you can directly deploy your application using VS2010 Publish option. This is very straight forward and described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh420322).